# Scikit-learn get propability of a sample belonging to a category

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Hello i'm trying to classify text into 4 categories an i'd like to print as well as the prediction, the probability of text to  belong to each category.
After reading documentation of Scikit-learn i think i should use `predict_proba`,
my code so far is this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

string = sys.argv[1] #i will pass text to predict from console
sets = load_files('scikit') #load training set




count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', ngram_range=(0, 3), min_df=1) 
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(sets.data)     


tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)


tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)



clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, sets.target)
docs_new = [string]
X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)
predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)
for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
     print('%r => %s' % (doc, sets.target_names[category])) #print prediction , and it is correct
     print(clf.predict_proba(sets.target_names)) #trying to get prob for al classes
```

sadly the output is this : `ValueError: objects are not aligned` , i've tried lot of different ways to achieve this and search a lot on the web but none seems working.
Any advice would be kindly appreciated. Thanks 
Nico.

Comment: _Where exactly_ does the error occur? When fitting the `MNB` classifier or somewhere else? If so, what kind of object is `sets.target`?

Comment: You'll get the probabilities with clf.predict_proba(X_new_tfidf)

Comment: @Stergios correct , feel free to post that as an answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to the predict_proba() function should be exactly the same with the input you give to the predict() method. Therefore, you'll get the probabilities with

```
clf.predict_proba(X_new_tfidf)
```